# Usergrid-InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace 'Usergrid_Applications' does not exist

Tags: usergrid

I install "Usergrid 2.1" follow by link
https://usergrid.apache.org/docs/installation/ug2-deploy-to-tomcat.html

But when I start tomcat, it throw exception as

```
(JobSchedulerService.java:118)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractScheduledService$1$1.run(Ab
stractScheduledService.java:174)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:95)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$301(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace 'Usergrid_Applications' does not
 exist)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$set_keyspace_result.read(Cassan
dra.java:5540)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_set_keyspace(Cassan
dra.java:540)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_keyspace(Cassandra.j
ava:527)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.client.HThriftClient.getCassandra
(HThriftClient.java:110)
```

How to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this problem for very long, i realized that in my case elasticsearch 1.7.6 as well as 2.x does not start without an additional config in **/etc/default/elasticsearch**.
Just adding this line **START_DAEMON=true** in the file and restarting elasticsearch worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Now able to connect to setup usergrid successfully. Had searched for the answer everywhere but could not find any reference till now. Hence thought of posting. 
The stack I am using is
 1. apache-usergrid-2.1.0
 2. cassandra 3.7
 3. tomcat8
 4. elasticsearch 2.4.4

I had almost given up on using usergrid due to this issue, Hope this is one of the solution that might help anyone looking for this issue.